# Object literals behaves weird in the console

Tags: javascript

In the JavaScript console (I'm using Chrome), the expression `{}` evaluates to `undefined`. If I execute `var a = {}`, the expression  `a` evaluates to `Object {}`. Why doesn't the expression `{}` evaluates to `Object {}`(in the console)?

Further more, `{a: 4}` seems to evaluate to `4`, and the expression `{a: 4, b: 5}` is apparently incorrect syntax.

Comment: `{}` doesn't actually evaluate to `undefined`, it just doesn't return anything. When you evaluate something in the Chrome console, what you're seeing afterwards is the return value of what you have executed

Comment: likewise the return value of {a:4} is 4. honestly I am not sure what this means, but i do not see any scenario where you would simply want to evaluate an expression like that. var a = {a: 4, b: 5} returns an object with keys a and b, and values 4 and 5

Comment: @JoshDavenport Hmm... What is the difference between the object literal `{}` and the array literal `[]` (beside the type object/array)? The array literal returns the value `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{}
```

is seen as a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) not an object

> A block statement is used to group zero or more statements. The
>   block is delimited by a pair of curly brackets.

Comment: And `{a: 4}` is a block as well, containing one expression statement `4`, marked by the label `a`.

Comment: [MDN: label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)