# Why does {} instanceof Object fails in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, instanceof

I am running the following JavaScript code in Google Chrome's console

```
{} instanceof Object
```

I get the following error.

[image]

I can work around the error if I add brackets

```
({}) instanceof Object
```

Now the output is the expected `true`

My question is why does this error occur? I don't think I am making a syntax mistake. Am I?

**Environment Details**

```
Version 48.0.2564.109 (64-bit)
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350006/object-literals-behaves-weird-in-the-console/23350254#23350254, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924988/why-does-foo-1-evaluate-to-1-in-the-console-and-foo-1-bar-2-resul/31925031#31925031 etc

Comment: `{}` is an object literal, not a reference to a object